# Does quantum espresso and VASP use same same self-consistent-field procedure?

Tags: density-functional-theory

The codes Quantum Espresso (QE) and Vienna Ab initio Simulation Package (VASP) both use plane wave basis sets and psuedopotentials. Most of the codes in both implementation of DFT uses Fortran code. Do they use similar self-consistent-field procedure to find the solutions of Kohn-Sham equations?

Comment: @Tyberius Yes. I would like to move this question to Materials Modeling SE. How to do that?

Comment: @phenomenon I don't believe the usual migration pathway is set up yet due it still being private beta. The quickest way would be for you to copy this question, join MMSE, and then repost it there. You should probably delete the question here after that or at least link to in the new questions. The SE sites like to avoid cross posting where a question is in two places at once.